# Mejora del editor de Markdown (accesibilidad Web)

Tags: soporte, característica-nueva, formato

#### Un poco de contexto

Desde que estoy en **Stack Overflow** me encontrado con el clásico editor de *Markdown*, es decir, algo como esto:

[image: El clásico editor de Markdown]

Una interfaz que deja poco margen de maniobra y que puede mejorarse.

Cuando empezamos a escribir sobre él, bien sea, **textos o fragmentos de código** nos encontramos con tres (03) inconvenientes importantes:

1. No tiene *indentación automática*. Es decir, que no se insertan los espacios automáticos (lo que ocurriría sin necesidad de presionar la tecla <kbd>Tab</kbd>) cuando se presiona la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Se escapa el foco del editor al presionar la tecla <kbd>Tab</kbd> en lugar de *indentar* (agregar espacios).
3. No tiene un **previsualizador** en la parte derecha. La idea es que mientras se escriba sobre el editor de *Markdown* se previsualice a la derecha y no en la parte inferior.

Entonces, teniendo claro el contexto, **¿qué posibilidad hay de implementar algo similar a esto?**

**Bien sea en el modo oscuro:**

[image: Vista Previa | Modo oscuro]

**O en el modo claro:**

[image: Vista previa | Modo claro]

Comment: Pregunta: ¿Como harias para darle formato y así incluir resaltado de sintasis a un textarea?.

Comment: Hola @DanielBriceño, ¿te refieres a las imágenes que se muestran en esta publicación?

Comment: a que te referis con identacion automatica? Lo del tab es cierto, y muchos lo solucionamos con un script en tampermonkey... y visualizador esta.. solo que abajo...

Comment: Igual, un cambio de este estilo, es para toda la red, y se deberia proponer en [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. si. La verdad me parece interesante la idea de agregarle un formato a una simple caja de texto como un `<textarea/>`.

Comment: Hola @gbianchi. Me refiero (con indentación/sangría automática) a que cuando se presione la tecla `Enter` no haya necesidad de presionar la tecla `Tab` para que agregue espacios. Tal y como funcionan en los editores de código.

Comment: Mañana publico en Meta esta publicación. Lo voy a traducir al inglés y luego lo publico. Les avisaré en cuanto esté allí.

Comment: Ya actualicé la publicación para clarificarla un poco más.

Comment: ¿Has visto que se está probando el [Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/209901)? Es una gran mejora. De momento solo está disponible en MetaSO y MetaSE, no aquí.

Comment: Hola @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'. Agrégala como respuesta y el enlace como referencia. Creo que sería de mucha utilidad. No sabía de la existencia de hecho. No te imaginas cuánto he estado deseando eso. Me entero de que se está trabajando en ello gracias a tu comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Meta.SE se planteó en enero de este año la pregunta [Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/209901). En ella explican que hay un nuevo editor en fase de prueba, que actualmente se puede probar en Meta Stack Exchange y Meta Stack Overflow (tienes que activarlo, está todo explicado en la publicación).

Fíjate cómo cambia una publicación al activarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si sale bien (y parece que es el caso), en poco tiempo debería estar disponible en todos los sitios.

Comment: Lo pude observar en Stack Overflow Team. Lo malo es que la tecla `Tab` aún se escapa. Espero que en el futuro tomen en cuenta ese detalle. Sin embargo, me parece genial que se esté trabajando en ello y me alegra mucho que hayas compartido esta información, que es de mucha utilidad. Lo estaré leyendo bien, de forma detallada para ir conociendo las novedades del editor.